# average case running time of randomized median selection

Tags: complexity-theory

here is an algorithm for finding median of an array of n(odd) distinct numbers.
what is the avg. running time of this algorithm

```
1. Uniformly at random, pick an entry i in A
2. Determine s, the number of entries in A that are smaller than i
3. If s = (n − 1)/2, then return i
4. Else goto 1
```

i am getting like theta(infinity), which is quit impossible. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can actually calculate the average run time of this algorithm, as it is possible that it would sometimes never complete - ie. your answer of infinite time is correct.

However, you can use probability to determine the "expected" time. Your question is essentially akin to "How many lottery tickets should I expect to buy before I win?" The probability of randomly picking the correct median is 1/n. So in order to get to P=1 you would expect to pick n times. Given that the time to determine whether the random selection is actually the median requires comparing it against every other entry, the expected overall time would be O(n^2), with best case of o(n) and worst case of o(infinity).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually I was asked expected time, not the average.